# Java RMI - Implementing Local to Implementing Remote

Tags: java, rmi

I understand and have coded up some RMI code and it works. I can create a RMIServer object and a RMIClient object and the client can send messages to the server and the server receives it perfectly.

My question is how do I communicate between two different computers in different parts of the world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect to the RMI server you provide an IP or name of the machine hosting the server. You will simply provide the IP/name of the RMI server in place of the one you're currently using.

Comment: How do I get my IP? So I could run the server on my machine then client could communicate to it if it know my ip/name? You explained that really well, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To get your ip, if you have windows go to start ->run-> write cmd. now in the console write ipconfig your ip is ADDRESS IP.
Remember, if you have dynamic ip (unless your supplier get  you a static ip) this change when restart your pc